# React JS how to avoid deep callbacks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My question is "Is there a way to avoid sending callbacks deep in the tree when I want to access/react upon child components data".

I have a component `Application` that contains a child component `Person` which in turn contains a child component `TraitCollection` which in turn contains a child component `Trait`.

When `Trait` is changed I want to send data back to `Application` to be forwarded to another child in `Application` named `PersonList`.

My current solution is to send callbacks as props to each child. Each callback function constructs and appends the data which finally reaches `Application` where I pass it down as a prop to `PersonList`.

I can imagine that "adding more levels", or splitting components up in more smaller parts will further complicate this callback chain.

Is there any other way to do this or is this the best way to handle passing data from children to parents in React?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are handling it is the **recommended** way and the most React-like. There is nothing wrong with that approach by itself other than the problem you have found. It looks like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/) could help you solve that problem. Redux lets you unify the state of your React application with the usage of a common store and a good design pattern based on action creators, actions and reducers.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will look into Redux!

Comment: Why do you think "there is nothing wrong with that approach"? if one ever changes the name of the callback, one must change the who-knows how many files which are all a tangled web of useless props where only the beginning and the end matter and everything between can only create potential complications and even break the whole delicate chain by a single mistake in one of its links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use React Context directly https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html, but better option will to use React-Redux, it will allow you to avoid passing callbacks and you will be able to change state of any component from any component (connected to the store) with dispatch function.

Answer (score 0):

The docs answer this directly:

> In large component trees, an alternative we recommend is to pass down a dispatch function from useReducer via context

From: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down
([Archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428025703/https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down))

Answer (score 0):

To avoid **Deep** `Callbacks`, according to [React](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) documentation, [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) via `context` as below:

**How to avoid passing callbacks down?**

We’ve found that most people don’t enjoy manually passing `callbacks` through every level of a component tree. Even though it is more explicit, it can feel like a lot of “`plumbing`”.

In large component trees, an alternative we recommend is to pass down a `dispatch` `function` from [useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) via `context`:

```
const TodosDispatch = React.createContext(null);

function TodosApp() {
  // Note: `dispatch` won't change between re-renders 
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todosReducer);
  return (
    <TodosDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <DeepTree todos={todos} />
    </TodosDispatch.Provider>
  );
}
```

Any `child` in the tree inside `TodosApp` can use the `dispatch` `function` to pass actions up to `TodosApp`:

```
function DeepChild(props) {
  // If we want to perform an action, we can get dispatch from context. 
  const dispatch = useContext(TodosDispatch);
  function handleClick() {
    dispatch({ type: 'add', text: 'hello' });
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Add todo</button>
  );
}
```

This is both more convenient from the maintenance perspective (no need to keep forwarding `callbacks`), and avoids the `callback` problem altogether. Passing `dispatch` **`down`** like this is the recommended pattern for **`deep`** **`updates`**.